# preparing view elements on a background thread

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

OK, so I know you're not supposed to directly interact with view elements from any thread other than the main thread.

But can you do stuff in a background thread that will be used by a view?

In particular, I have a pretty substantial algorithm that ends up spitting out a string. If I want that string to become the text of a UITextView, do I need to run this whole algorithm on the main thread? Or can it be done in the background ?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly run it in the background, just like a graphical application might render images in the background. Once you have the string ready, GCD is your friend:

```
- (void)backgroundStringGenerator
{
    NSString *expensiveString = ... // do string generation algorithm

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        theLabel.text = expensiveString;
    });
}
```